# Can the Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource work without a default DataSource?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to implement a multi-tenant DataSource in Spring using AbstractRoutingDataSource. I don't want any default DataSource because it is not a valid scenario in my case. During startup, determineCurrentLookupKey() is being called (I don't know from where). My context is not yet loaded at this point so determineCurrentLookupKey() returns a null value and I get this exception:

`Cannot determine target DataSource for lookup key [null]`

Is there a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: You are using JPA and that is trying to validate/check th database for metadata hence it needs a connection to the database, you can disable this with a hibernate property. Or if you are using something like flyway/liquibase to manage your db that will also need a connection.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and adding the `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` didn't work for me...
And actually, I'm not sure that this is a really good solution to disable these validations...

But I found another solution!

[setLenientFallback(boolean)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html#setLenientFallback(boolean))

> public void setLenientFallback(boolean lenientFallback)

> Specify whether to apply a lenient fallback to the default DataSource if no specific DataSource could be found for the current lookup key.
> Default is "true", accepting lookup keys without a corresponding entry in the target DataSource map - simply falling back to the default DataSource in that case.

> Switch this flag to "false" if you would prefer the fallback to only apply if the lookup key was null. Lookup keys without a DataSource entry will then lead to an IllegalStateException.

probably this is what you're looking for?

But if the lookup key will be `null` the default DataSource still will be called...

**UPD**:

If you want completely get rid of setting the default DataSource you need to remove `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` from your `application.yaml`, coz this is the reason why Spring trying to get this connection during the context initialization. This worked for me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, hibernate was trying to get some metadata. It can be disabled with: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
OR
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

[See here](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/multitenant-hibernate-spring-boot-how-to-prevent-it-from-looking-up-for-a-connection-during-server-startup/3806)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).